# Is it possible to set Pika SelectConnection polling interval?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, pika

I am using ***Asynchronous consumer example*** from pika doc to test my rabbitmq server.

from log I found that the messages were consumed for each 5-sec interval.

I am wondering is it possbile to set the interval value, e.g. 50ms.
I have searched the source code, but cannot find any method used to set this interval value.

Can someone help on this? thx

this is part of the test log.

```
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:03,726 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 49 from None: 3806.8 09:52:01 900 09:52:02.638261 09:52:02.638261 09:52:03.726126
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:03,726 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 49
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:03,735 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 50 from None: 3806.8 09:52:02 400 09:52:03.139585 09:52:03.139585 09:52:03.735155
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:03,735 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 50
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:03,744 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 51 from None: 3807.0 09:52:02 900 09:52:03.640902 09:52:03.640902 09:52:03.744174
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:03,744 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 51
.
.
.
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:08,707 __main__                      on_message                           279 : Received message # 58 from None: 3806.2 09:52:06 400 09:52:07.151268 09:52:07.151268 09:52:08.707362
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:08,707 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 58
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:08,716 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 59 from None: 3806.8 09:52:06 900 09:52:07.643560 09:52:07.643560 09:52:08.716389
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:08,716 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 59
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:08,726 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 60 from None: 3806.6 09:52:07 400 09:52:08.146888 09:52:08.146888 09:52:08.726413
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:08,726 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 60
.
.
.
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:13,653 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 61 from None: 3806.4 09:52:07 900 09:52:08.648231 09:52:08.648231 09:52:13.653395
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:13,653 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 61
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:13,662 __main__                       on_message                           279 : Received message # 62 from None: 3806.2 09:52:08 400 09:52:09.415229 09:52:09.415229 09:52:13.662424
INFO       2019-08-28 09:52:13,662 __main__                       acknowledge_message                  288 : Acknowledging message 62
```

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: SelectConnection does not poll. You have a bug in your code. Please discuss this here: [`pika-python`](https://groups.google.com/forum/?pli=1#!topic/pika-python/wCDHFeP-s8g).

Comment: thx, I have found the issue. the problem is the publisher code I was using, which gave a very low efficiency of publishing, causing a 5-sec delay.